# CSS layout inside layout

Tags: css, layout

I have a layout frame of small widget with top navbar and bottom navbar. Inside that widget i have items and in one of them i have to put another layout(same as parent). [This is small example of mine css problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYZyVZ), where footer in child layout is not in the bottom.

```
.body{
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.main{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.item{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.view{
    height: 100%;
}
```

this dont get the height of height in parent widget, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to build the layout i want without any kind of positions, i removed all of them. I use:

```
display: table;
display: table-row;
```

for mine layout and it works perfectly. [Here is the example of what i did](http://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/RNbyqP?editors=110). Below is general css of what i did.

```
.body{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.header{
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.footer{
    display: table-row;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.main{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.item{
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.fullExtend{
    height: 100%;
}
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Class body is container for widget, header and footer is for header and footer for each widget, main is the body of widget, item is part of main which can be widget and fullExtend is item which height get maximum space left in page.

Comment: Perfect, Add some of the code you did in the response and accept it as your answer!

Comment: Plus side bars in `display: table-row` is simple enough

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve something like this?

Edit: I refined your structure a bit. You want to achieve this?

HTML :

```
<div class="main-header">
    Main Header
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="item item-1">

            <div class="header">
                Item 1 Header
            </div>

            <div class="item-content">
                <div class="item item-2">
                    Item 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                Item 1 Footer
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-footer">
    Main Footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.main-header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkblue; 
  color: white;
}
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
}
.item{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.item-view{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item-content{
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: you make item view absolute, and it has lost it own place(relative). In below example you can see that item 1 is lost http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYgQez?editors=110

Comment: I edited the response and the codepen do you want to achieve this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBwygP

Comment: No.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBwygP , .wrapper should be container for many items and on of that items could be another widget(with footer,header and wrapper)

Comment: I guess i can't do height till end of container with position: relative